# System requirements for the hardware

Tags: spring, h2, corda

Tell me, please, what are the approximate system requirements for the hardware for Corda's stable operation? While we plan to deploy 2 nodes (notarial and a node of our company) working on the Spring-server?

Answer (score 1):

A guide is available for Corda Enterprise [here](http://docs.corda.r3.com/sizing-and-performance.html). The high-level requirements are:

- Small: 1GB JVM heap, 1 core, 2GB to 3GB minimum host RAM
- Medium: 4GB JVM heap, 8 cores, 8GB minimum host RAM
- Large: 8GB JVM heap, 32 cores, 16GB minimum host RAM